# Existing eCommerce Framework vs custom eCommerce solution for Scalability

Tags: php, woocommerce, e-commerce, prestashop, scalability

We are planning to start an ecommerce startup and are evaluating scalability options for choosing between (PrestaShop/WooCommerce/OpenCart) or our own custom ecommerce solution.

We have thought of the following optimization techniques for scalability:

1) CDN for static resources.

2) Load balancer for horizontal scaling once the traffic goes high.

3) MemCached or APCU cache for caching database queries.

4) APC Cache for PHP ByteCode Caching.

5) Making sure all images are compressed losslessly.

6) Minifying CSS and JS of theme.

7) Enabling mod_deflate or mod_gzip for compression.

8) Master Slave Replication once DB starts to become a bottleneck.

9) Making sure unnecessary Apache modules are disabled.

10) Making sure unnecessary Prestashop modules are disabled.

What would you recommend? A custom eCommerce solution or we can optimize one of these frameworks(PrestaShop, WooCommerce, OpenCart etc) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation is PrestaShop:

1) It has CDN support

2) No "special" support (it supports master/slave DB servers)

3 & 4) Has MemCached, APC & xcache

5) Not supported by default, but has Smush.it paid module

6) Full suppoert - CCC i.e. Combine (all .js in one file, etc), Compress (minify js, css, html & Cache - the combined files in cache folder with timestamp based expiration)

7) Integrated mod_deflate, you can always enable mod_gzip at the .htaccess file

8) You can configure master (this is the default one) & slave servers, and the core PrestaShop queries support master/slave (i.e. some queries are passed to slave and they have specified which exactly). Most of the 3rd party modules does not use that feature.

9 & 10) These are the thing the administrator/developer must take care.

Custom solution is a worst case, unless if you have 1+ year and  lot money to invest. I don't like Magento & OpenCart and that's why 5 years ago I chose PrestaShop for eCommerce developement. Magento has unnecessarily complex class tree and of course the developers charge usually a lot more, because they have a lot of work :), and OpenCart is a way below the others - having not a single comment in the code is a just not professional, no indexes at all on the database tables, it does not even uses template engine. Regarding the "WooCommerce" - using CMS system for eCommerce is just not serious.

My advice is to check PrestaShop - get the latest version, test it, check at addons.prestashop.com (The official Marketplace) for the modules you will need. Also, there's a newly released "PrestaShop Cloud" - you can take a look on it as well.

Answer (score 4):

Since others have given their comments on each solutions I will give you more overall idea.

`PrestaShop/WooCommerce/OpenCart` - These products are somewhat mature according to my knowledge.

Advantages

- minimizes the time and efforts involved in the website building process.
- plug-and-play functionality.
- regular updates with bug fixes and new features.
- stable and well-tested code.
- help from the community.

Disadvantages

- invest time to learn.
- a lot of unnecessary code.
- you’ll need to tweak a ready-to-use framework to meet your requirements, which will take additional time.
- your website will look like all the rest.
- additional third party integration step (possibly in the form of bloated jQuery plugins or similar).
- no control over the code.
- extra effort on security since your architecture is well known.
- As you think you can't edit the core files since it will crash the system in the next update.

`own custom e-commerce solution` - There are pros and cons using your own e-commerce solution rather than an existing products.

Advantages

- will save you time and effort in the future because it was built precisely to your long-term needs.
- will not need to learn how to use or customize it.
- optimized to satisfy only your needs, not everyone’s.
- only what you need and in the way you need it. No unnecessary stuff, no bloated code.
- full control over the code and its design implementation.
- Complete modularity. The flexibility of your framework depends only on you.
- A unified code base. You can minimize the need of third party components, which means less mix-and-match work.
- Uniqueness of your website is 100% guaranteed.
- no effort on security since your architecture is not known

Disadvantages

- more time and effort.
- You need to test and maintain the code.
- bug fixes, updates, and new features are built by you.

To find out whether it’s a proper decision for you too, you need to answer the following questions:

- Am I capable to create it?
- Do I have enough free/extra time to do it?
- Is it reasonable to make it?

  If you are going to use PrestaShop/WooCommerce/OpenCart, I would advice you to check out [Magento](http://magento.com/) as well. Hope this answers your question.

Also note that your considered optimisation techniques for scalability aspects are
good but there is a lot more to be considered if you are willing to learn. I can help you with them as well.

Answer (score 1):

First of all its not frameworks its cms. Frameworks: laravel, symphony and etc..

And u can do all things with all cms. But to my mind the best - prestashop.

2) Lot of ways to optimize your server, your cms, write correct modules .
3) In prestashop you can use memcached
4) You can install APC on server and enable it in prestashop performance
5) You can edit compression settings or write/buy powerful module to get such effect
6) Minifying CSS / JS / HTML in performance (settings)
7) mod_gzip in server settings
8) Disable overrides or non prestashop modules. Do profiling to check MS and bad modules.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. What do you mean by MS?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking at developing on top of any of the existing open source carts out there, have a good look at the code first.  Just a quick look and I can make these comments:

WooCommerce -- OK if you're used to the wordpress style of code I guess but it locks you into using that specific CMS as your development framework.

PrestaShop -- Coding standards are a bit outdated (no PSR compliance), no use of namespaces, code has some but not comprehensive API documentation.

OpenCart -- code has almost no comments, no use of namespaces, limited PSR compliance, no API documentation.

Have you considered Magento 2.0 which is in beta?  Magento 1 had the limitation of no namespaces because it relied on Zend Framework 1 which was pre-namespace but Magento 2.0 has namespace support while not throwing the baby out with the bathwater (Zend 1 classes have been kept and wrapped in namespaced classes).

If you're looking at extreme flexibility and the ability to code things your own way, you may be better off starting from scratch on top of one of the existing PHP frameworks (Laravel, Yii2, etc).  In terms of performance you're not likely to gain much -- you're apt to make just as many performance mistakes building your own code as you will find in someone else's code.  However this will be a lot of work!  eBay bought Magento for $180 million and that wasn't because it was knocked together by a couple of guys in a week or two -- there is some serious programming work in all of these systems.

Answer (score 1):

Building your own custom eCommerce solution from scratch can be a real nightmare for a startup and should generally be avoided.

Usually what happens a few months later is that the startup ends up having to maintain code, fix bugs and create new features internally. This all adds up and eats into time that could be better spent working on other more important aspects of your startup. There's no point re-inventing the wheel!

Eventually the startup decides to bite the bullet and scrap what they built out for several months for an off the shelf solution. They then choose a downloaded platform like Prestashop/WooCommerce/OpenCart etc.. that they feel they can then customise. This again takes time to both learn, implement and tailor to your specific needs; taking you away from other more important activities.

If you're looking for a lightweight and scalable solution that is quick to integrate, low maintainance, with no bloated code base and is super customisable you could look at more modern methodologies like [eCommerce APIs](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=ecommerce%20api).

These services are usually already heavily optimized for increased performance. They are usually available globally in multiple regions, load balanced, provide asset CDNs and some allow for custom data structures etc...

The beauty with this approach is that you can pick the components you need to integrate, without having to disable modules. You can also decide in the future that you need to change or add to your frontend technology stack and even pick a different programming language.

You could even build static sites that talk to these APIs and host a few files that make up your site in an Amazon S3 bucket for a few cents a month!?